# Cygwin cmake undefined reference to `__imp_stream_free'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, cmake, cygwin

при компиляции программы в Cygwin путем сборки cmake и дальше make
вывод содержит кучу строк undefined reference to *

при компиляции этого же софта в линукс все компилируется правильно.

CMakeList.txt файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/")

file(GLOB main_src
    "*.h"
    "*.c"
)


add_executable(main ${main_src})



# Search OpenSSL
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(OPENSSL REQUIRED openssl)

if( OPENSSL_FOUND )
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "Using OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
else()
    # Error; with REQUIRED, pkg_search_module() will throw an error by it's own
endif()

target_link_libraries(main ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

содержимое файла CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt

```
/usr/bin/c++.exe    -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/main.dir/activation.c.o [..]  -o main.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libmain.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lssl -lcrypto
```

Сообщение которое выдает make

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_extend'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_extend'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x531): undefined reference to `__imp_freerdp_usleep'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x567): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_extend'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `__imp_freerdp_usleep'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x6db): undefined reference to `__imp_wait_obj_set'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x785): undefined reference to `__imp_wait_obj_get_fds'
CMakeFiles/rdpscan.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x7b7): undefined reference to `__imp_wait_obj_clear'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x94c): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0x99a): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_extend'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xad3): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_free'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xb6e): undefined reference to `__imp_xzalloc'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xbb6): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xbca): undefined reference to `__imp_wait_obj_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xbe3): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xbfb): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_new'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xc51): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_free'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xc64): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_free'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xc78): undefined reference to `__imp_stream_free'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xc8c): undefined reference to `__imp_wait_obj_free'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/transport.c.o:transport.c:(.text+0xcc6): undefined reference to `__imp_xfree'
```

Comment: `undefined reference to` говорит о невозможности найти реализацию указанной функции. И если тот же самый код удачно собирается в нативной среде, то дело, скорее всего, в разных версиях подключаемых библиотек. Попробуйте минимизировать пример и проверить эту гипотезу.

Comment: Есть ещё варианты ? в самой новой версии ubuntu такие же сообщения выдаются. если добавить разные параметры -W и -Wl то сообщения исчезают но какие то другие ерроры.

Comment: Разрядность библиотек и приложения проверить. Всё должно совпадать. Например, если приложение 64бит, то и все либы должны быть 64бит. И наоборот.